# Adsquery Handle error

Tags: sql, lazarus

Using a TAdsquery component (11.1) in Lazarus IDE 1.014 with the following syntax in the string editor. The query works fine in a DBgrid only while in design mode and set to active. It also works in the Advanatge Data Archetect.
However, trying to open it from code during or after compliation the code or component gives me a 'fails to get a handle error'. (tried both ways) Checked all the tables and they appear OK. (4 tables are involved in the query). The following is the query in the string editor:
    Select
    FOOD_DES.Long_Desc,
    NUTR_DEF.NutrDesc,
    NUT_DATA.Nutr_No,
    NUT_DATA.Nutr_Val,
    NUT_DATA.Num_Data_Pts,
    NUT_DATA.Std_Error,
    NUT_DATA.Src_Cd,
    NUT_DATA.Deriv_Cd,
    SYNC.NDB_no As NDB_no1
    From
    FOOD_DES Inner Join
    SYNC On FOOD_DES.NDB_No = SYNC.NDB_no,
    NUTR_DEF,
    NUT_DATA
    Where
    NUTR_DEF.Nutr_No = NUT_DATA.Nutr_No And
    NUT_DATA.NDB_No = SYNC.NDB_no
    Order By
    NDB_no1

This is my attempt at opening it with code but I get the same 'handle error'

```
adsQuery1.Close;{close the query}
//assign new SQL expression
adsQuery1.SQL.Clear;
adsQuery1.SQL.Add ('Select   FOOD_DES.Long_Desc,NUTR_DEF.NutrDesc,NUT_DATA.Nutr_No,NUT_DATA.Nutr_Val,NUT_DATA.Num_Data_Pts,NUT_DATA.Std_Error,NUT_DATA.Src_Cd,NUT_DATA.Deriv_Cd,SYNC.NDB_no As NDB_no1');
adsQuery1.SQL.Add ('FROM FOOD_DES Inner Join SYNC On FOOD_DES.NDB_No = SYNC.NDB_no, NUTR_DEF,NUT_DATA');
adsQuery1.SQL.Add ('WHERE NUTR_DEF.Nutr_No = NUT_DATA.Nutr_No And NUT_DATA.NDB_No = SYNC.NDB_no');
adsQuery1.RequestLive := true;
adsQuery1.Open;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if I am setting all the parameters correctly in the properties dialog and/or the code. The components are Adsquery1 linked to Datasource13 and to DBgrid1.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a parameter query in advantage as you use the 'where' statement.
You need to set the parameters first (in this case, string and input) in the object inspector and then us this as a guide.

```
AdsQuery1.Params[0].AsString := (ndb);
AdsQuery1.Params[1].AsString := (nut_num);
AdsQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT  tablename field etc
WHERE age = ndb_no =:ndb and nutr_no = :nut_num';
AdsQuery1.Open;
DataSource1.DataSet := AdsQuery1; (datasource could be connected to a grid)
```